# How can I quantify whether locations of one 'type' are closer to one another compared to a second 'type'?

Tags: coordinate-system, r, gps, distance, spatial-analysis

This might have an obvious answer but I'm new to GIS and can't seem to find the right technique... I've got GPS points for a bunch of households and have calculated the distance (in km) between each pair of houses. Each household can be one of two types (which I have assigned) - let's say 'jock' and 'nerd'. I want to quantify whether nerd households are physically closer to one another within a neighbourhood compared to jock households. I'm kind of looking for a measure of isolation or segregation... What would be the best approach?

(NB: there are not equal numbers of jock and nerd households in the dataset.)

I've looked into techniques such as cluster analysis, principle coordinate analysis and dissimilarity matrices, but none of these seem right. I've even tried doing t-tests and Mann-Whitney tests on the distances categorised by household type but there are so many dyads that the tiniest difference between groups comes out as statistically significant.

Comment: this sounds like a question for http://datascience.stackexchange.com/, since the GIS part is already complete :-)... or http://stats.stackexchange.com/